# How to access cookies in Django TestCase request and responses?

Tags: django, django-views, setcookie, testcase

I have a view that sets a cookie using `response.set_cookie` method. I would like to test if the cookie is being set in a `TestCase`.

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.cookies), the cookie should be accessible in the client object, but `client.cookies.items` returns an empty list. The cookie is being correctly set in the browser.

Test case:

```
>>> response = self.client.get(url)
>>> self.client.cookies.items()
[]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the test case.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing and looking through the `TestClient` source it seems clear that cookies should be available on the client and the response https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L411 If you are using the session middleware then at a minimum you would have a session cookie.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the response's client instance:

```
response = self.client.get(url)
response.client.cookies.items()
```

Comment: Why does this work instead of `self.client.cokies.items()`?

Comment: I can't remember. According to the current documentation it should work with self.client.cookies in version 1.6+. I haven't checked older docs, but maybe in 1.3 (or so) the test client did not capture the cookies and only the response client did.

Answer (score 0):

`response.cookies` also works...

```
response = self.client.get(f'/authors/{author.id}/')
print(response.cookies)
>>> Set-Cookie: user=154; expires=Tue, 17 Oct 2028 00:31:19 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
```

...but if you are repeatedly using `self.client`, doesn't seems safe:

```
response = self.client.get(f'/apps/library/authors/{author.id}/')
print("cookies: ", response.cookies)

# Some random testing...

response = self.client.get(f'/apps/library/authors/{author.id}/')
print("cookies: ", response.cookies)

>>> cookies:  Set-Cookie: user=584; expires=Tue, 17 Oct 2028 02:34:41 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Path=/
>>> cookies:
```

`response.client.cookies` works just fine with repeated `self.client` requests:

```
response = self.client.get(f'/apps/library/authors/{author.id}/')
print("\ncookies: ", response.cookies)

# Some random testing...

response = self.client.get(f'/apps/library/authors/{author.id}/')
print("\ncookies: ", response.cookies)

>>> cookies:  Set-Cookie: user=97; expires=Tue, 17 Oct 2028 02:44:40 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Path=/
>>> cookies:  Set-Cookie: user=97; expires=Tue, 17 Oct 2028 02:44:40 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Path=/
```

#### Side Note

If you want to access `user` value, this is the syntax:

```
response.client.cookies["user"].value
>>> 154
```

`response.client.cookies["user"]` is an [http.cookies.Morsel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html#morsel-objects) object, so accessing the `value` of the cookie itself, is different than accessing a regular dictionary.